# cannot access class jdk.xml.internal.JdkXmlUtils

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, java-11

I'm updating an old Company-intern extension for hybris/SAP-Commerce (2005). it's an extension to consume an API.

I don't know how old the extension is.

However, while applying it to java 11, I spot problems like this ([Java 11: import javax.xml.ws.WebFault: "Cannot resolve symbol ws"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57318521/java-11-import-javax-xml-ws-webfault-cannot-resolve-symbol-ws)).

After rerun the command ./hybrisserver.sh, a given (read only) '.jar' file throws follow exception:

```
Failed to instantiate [<class from given .jar>]:
            Constructor threw exception;
        nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError:
            class com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.Catalog (in unnamed module @0x9a92113) cannot access class jdk.xml.internal.JdkXmlUtils (in module java.xml) because module java.xml does not export jdk.xml.internal to unnamed module @0x9a92113
```

I thought it could be a jdk problem, so I tried different distributions.
(I'm working on Manjaro Linux KDE 20.1 with sdkman)
Follow distributions I've tested:

```
 Vendor        | Version      | Dist    | Identifier
--------------------------------------------------------
 AdoptOpenJDK  | 11.0.8.j9    | adpt    | 11.0.8.j9-adpt      
 Java.net      | 11.0.8       | open    | 11.0.8-open       
 SAP           | 11.0.8       | sapmchn | 11.0.8-sapmchn
```

Each of it throw the same error

Comment: It would be useful to know the name of the JAR file, is that your own or is it maintained by someone else? Do they have an issue tracker to submit bugs? One thing you could do it point the maintainers to the java.xml.catalog API (new since Java 9) which provides a standard/supported API for resolving external resources.

Comment: If you are able, please share a reproducer that emits that error message.

Answer (score 9):

This is not a JDK bug, or fault in your JVM installation(s).  It is actually a problem with the old code you are trying to build.  The code is using a class in a JVM internal package.  It shouldn't do that.  It shouldn't *need to* do that.

It has always been a bad idea to directly use classes in internal packages since they are subject to change without any notice.  The old Java documentation has included warnings about this ... for as long as I can remember.

As of Java 9, the module system will (by default) prevent application code from accessing internal APIs.  And that is what you are running into here.

There are two ways to solve this:

- The better way is to modify the code you are trying to compile so that it no longer depends on that class.  (We can't offer suggestions as to *how* to do this without seeing your code ...)
- The other way is to use `--add-opens` options in the `java` command line to break module encapsulation to allow access the class.  The following should do it for code that doesn't use modules.

  ```
  --add-opens java.xml/jdk.xml.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
  ```

  **WARNING**: this approach should be viewed as a *short term work-around*. The internal API you are using *could* be changed or removed with the next Java release.

---

**NOTE** : as of JDK 10, the `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.Catalog` class no longer exists in the OpenJDK source code.  It has been replaced by `javax.xml.catalog.Catalog`.  My guess is that you are getting the "internal" version from a dependency rather than the JDK.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using maven to build your project you should add the JVM argument :

```
--add-opens java.xml/jdk.xml.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
```

for example :

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                 <argLine>--add-opens java.xml/jdk.xml.internal=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: But note that this should be treated as a show-term workaround.  It may stop working.  The **correct** fix is to change your code to replace this use of an internal class with something more appropriate; see my answer.  (Alan Bateman's comment may provide a clue in this particular case.)