# can not clean and build web app in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java-11, netbeans-12, tomcat10

i have a web project in netbeans when i try to clean and build it this error raises

```
error: option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed with target 11
```

cross checked all dependencies, all jar files are included. But project can be deployed in tomcat( i am suspecting older version of war is being deployed) can any one help ?

### app clean and dist log

```
    ant -f /xx/xx/app -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild -DforceRedeploy=false -Dbrowser.context=/xx/xx/app clean dist
    init:
    undeploy-clean:
    deps-clean:
    galeva_base.init:
    galeva_base.deps-clean:
    Updating property file: /xx/xx/base_project/build/built-clean.properties
    Deleting directory /xx/xx/base_project/build
    base_project.clean:
    do-clean:
    Deleting directory /xx/xx/app/build
    check-clean:
    clean:
    init:
    deps-module-jar:
    base_project.init:
    base_project.deps-jar:
    Created dir: /xx/xx/base_project/build
    Updating property file: /xx/xx/base_project/build/built-jar.properties
    Created dir: /xx/xx/base_project/build/classes
    Created dir: /xx/xx/base_project/build/empty
    Created dir: /xx/xx/base_project/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
    Compiling 40 source files to /xx/xx/base_project/build/classes
    base_project.compile:
    Created dir: /xx/xx/base_project/dist
    Copying 1 file to /xx/xx/base_project/build
    Copy libraries to /xx/xx/base_project/dist/lib.
    Building jar: /xx/xx/base_project/dist/base_project.jar
    To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
    java -jar "/xx/xx/base_project/dist/base_project.jar"
   base_project.deploy:
    base_project.jar:
    deps-ear-jar:
    deps-jar:
    Created dir: /xx/xx/app/build/web/WEB-INF/classes
    Created dir: /xx/xx/app/build/web/META-INF
    Copying 1 file to /xx/xx/app/build/web/META-INF
    Copying 3 files to /xx/xx/app/build/web
    library-inclusion-in-archive:
    Copying 1 file to /xx/xx/app/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
    Copying 1 file to /xx/xx/app/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
    library-inclusion-in-manifest:
    Created dir: /xx/xx/app/build/empty
    Created dir: /xx/xx/app/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
    Compiling 17 source files to /xx/xx/app/build/web/WEB-INF/classes
    error: option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed with target 11
    BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

### openjdk version

jdk 11

### Netbeans version

12.3

### Tomcat version

Tomcat 10

Comment: There are several possible solutions to this issue, but [the simplest is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57292637/2985643) to _"simply set empty value to `endorsed.classpath=` at `project.properties file`_". Also search SO for _"option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed with target"_ for other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

ANT is using Java 1.6 JRE by default which is not suitable anymore for Java 11 features.
Defining a source and target version fixed it for me on using maven, which behaves the same way in that case.

```
<property name="ant.build.javac.source" value="11"/>
<property name="ant.build.javac.target" value="11"/>
```

Comment: The OP is using Ant, not Maven, as their build tool. So showing your Maven settings can't possibly answer the question.